# Base64 string reduces after putting Map (data structure) into json.decode(map)

Tags: flutter, dart, base64

I am converting an Image to base64 and then I am putting it into the Map data structure, but when I convert Map into the JSON string, base64 string reduces and gets the reduced length response from the server. My question is why is Map reducing it?

> "Message": "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."

Converting Image file to Base64

```
                    var imageBytes = pfImage.readAsBytesSync();
                    String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
                    print("base64 is =$base64Image");
```

putting into the map

```
                  var petData = Map<String, dynamic>();

                  petData['user_id'] = 55;
                  petData['name'] = "sdf";
                  petData['breed'] = "dsf";
                  petData['StrImageBase64'] =base64Image != null ? base64Image : "";
```

converting to json string

```
print("map>>" + json.encode(map));
```

**Some More Info**

I have checked it locally as well by putting base64string into map and then print it, the result is in reduced string.

```
                 petData['StrImageBase64'] ="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";
                 print("json.encode =${json.encode(petData)}");
```

**UPDATED**

It is not **possible**, that the map can reduce the value, or Json.decode(map) returns the reduced base64 string, Actually its VS code editor issue for not showing full base64 value.

Comment: If you print the `petData['StrImageBase64']` after putting the base64Image on it, it prints the base64 String or print the empty String `""`?

Comment: not empty, it has string but reduced,

Comment: Edited: sorry its full string not reduced but I separately checked it. if I put all data and then print the map, then base64 reduced

Comment: Probably its not really reduced. Only not showing all the base64 String at print. To confirm, can you print the lenght of the `base64` String and the lenght of `petData['StrImageBase64']`?

Comment: I have checked it, it is confirmed, basically when I put the map into json.encode(map) function, then it reduces the base64 string, I don't know why.

Comment: @AdemirVillenaZevallos you are right its vscode editor issue, values are same not reducing, Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, happy coding :)